# find by id with ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the next code:

```
this.state.list.find(item => item.id === id)
```

I'm finding the short version for that, I think something like that(Obviously, not work because the name of item.id conflict with id):

```
this.state.list.find(({id}) => id === id)
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: this.state.list.find(({id}) => id)

Comment: @PiyushZalani That will always just return the very first element if there is one.

Comment: You can rename id into something else: `({id: iid}) => iid === id`

Comment: This is what @Jorge is trying to do in this question, and that is possibly one of the ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use destructuring reassignment, but honestly I don't think it saves you much here.

```
this.state.list.find(({id: itemId}) => id === itemId);
```